# Lock and Edit - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: content-editor, workflow

When I click on "Lock and Edit" I am getting the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CheckOut.Execute(CommandContext context) +297
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Dispatcher.Dispatch(Message message, CommandContext context) +209
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.HandleMessage(Message message) +1713
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +152
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +547
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297
```

Comment: can you check the item you are trying to lock and edit has the correct language and version?

Comment: Same error for multiple language versions.

Comment: does this mean each language version you are editing has numbered version also?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There is always a version 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was fixed by adding a green check box for the "Workflow State Write" permission for each of the Writable workflow steps.

Comment: I had the same error and it was workflow related, but was solved by fixing the incorrectly entered "<r //>" in the lock field.